# Wake on Lan via internet

Tags: wake-on-lan

Currently I am trying to wake up my desktop computer at home from elsewhere. I am approaching it as the following:

1. In my TP-link router I openend the UDP 9 port and forwarded it to the local IP of my desktop computer (192.168.0.103).
2. Filling in my public IP and the MAC address of my desktop on this website: http://www.dslreports.com/wakeup.
3. Press Wake Up!

Waking my desktop up in a LAN environment works fine, but via the internet it doesn't work. I would really appreciate suggestions that can help me out.

Comment: Are you trying to achieve this through code? If so add your code.

Comment: I tried it with the wakeonlan command in the terminal. As the following:
wakeonlan -i 192.168.1.255 -p 1234 01:02:03:04:05:06, i.e.
wakeonlan -i [public IP]       -p [UDP port] [MAC address]

Comment: I don't think this is the right place to ask. I don't think this has anything to do with coding. You could try asking it [here](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thank you for the help!